# Is it possible in Scala to simplify the following if/else statement?

Tags: scala

I'm trying to store the maximum price. There are some other business rules in there but the three nested if statements look very procedural and messy. I'm wondering if there is a nicer more functional way to express the following logic.

```
val sunsetTime1 = "14:00:00.000"
val maxPrices = new HashMap[String, Double]

if (trade.dateTime.before(time1)) {
  if (maxPrices.contains(sunsetTime1)) {
    if (maxPrices(sunsetTime1) < trade.price) {
      maxPrices.put(sunsetTime1, price)
    }
  }
  else {
    maxPrices.put(sunsetTime1, price)
  }

}
```

Comment: This looks like a fragment of an imperative loop. Maybe you can post the whole method, including what `price`, `trade` and `time1` are.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm not an Scala expert, and you should check that code, but I guess pattern matching and Options are more Idiomatic Scala.

```
if (trade.dateTime.before(time1)) {
  maxPrices.get(sunsetTime1) match {
    case Some(oldPrice) if oldPrice < trade.price => maxPrices.put(sunsetTime1, price)
    case None => maxPrices.put(sunsetTime1, price)
  }
}
```

Cheers.

Answer (score 7):

The statement (the outer if, I ignore) is of the form:

```
if (a) 
  if (b) 
    c
else 
  c
```

in a table of combinations, we can write it:

```
      a
   | t| f
  --------
  t| c| c
b --------
  f| -| c
```

If a is false (right column), we do c, independently from a. If a is true, we do a b-check, and c is only done if b is true.

We can write it as

```
if (! (a && !b)) c
```

or

```
if (!a || b) c
```

The last form is more concise, but more functional? 
Thanks to the corrections in the comment. When in doubt, use testcases, or take the longer form.

Comment: Humm.. By your logic wouldn't the @OP update the map if `!(maxPrices(sunsetTime1) < trade.price)`? I really think that something went wrong with that logic table and the real simplification would be `if(!a || b)`. That would make sense (and it is kind of what I'm doing in my answer).

Comment: @Anthony Accioly: Yeah, the dash should be in the bottom-left of the table rather than the top-right.

Comment: Condition 1 (a) is: `(maxPrices.contains(sunsetTime1))`. If this is true, then a second condition is checked (b) := `(maxPrices(sunsetTime1) < trade.price)`. So if a is true and b is true, then c. Or shorter: If (a && b) c. But if a is false (the else part), then c as well. If a is false, there is no b checked, ... oh, it's confusing. I'm swimming. Yes, the dash belongs into the lower left.

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty inexperienced in Scala, but my functional programming instincts tell me something like this:

```
if (trade.dateTime.before(time1)) {
  maxPrices get(sunsetTime1) 
  filterNot ( _ < trade.price ) 
  orElse ( maxPrices.put(sunsetTime1, price) )
}
```

AFAIK, the only difference from the original version is that it returns the old value rather than an AnyVal if a higher price was already in the map.

(If any real Scalistas disagree with any of this, please do feel free to comment.)

Comment: Maybe you can warn that it will only works for mutable map (even if it seems to be the case in the given example).